# Length of a parametric curve (integral of differential of the curve)

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, curve

I am trying to learn differential geometry and sympy for the first time. Using sympy , I am able to define expressions for parametric curve and find velocities. I am trying to compute the length of the curve as per the below definition, but unable to figure out, how to do this with sympy.
Can someone please provide pointers on how to compute the curve length.

[image]

Below is the current code I have (using sympy & matplotlib).

```
# Expression of Parametric Curve 
t = sympy.symbols('t')
x_expr = sympy.cos(t)
y_expr = sympy.sin(t)

f_x = sympy.lambdify(t, x_expr, 'numpy')
f_y = sympy.lambdify(t, y_expr, 'numpy')

# Differential of Parametric Curve 
diff_x = sympy.lambdify(t, sympy.diff(x_expr, t), 'numpy')
diff_y = sympy.lambdify(t, sympy.diff(y_expr, t), 'numpy')

t_values = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 80, endpoint=True)

X = f_x(t_values)
Y = f_y(t_values)

# Plot the curve
clear_figure()
ax = create_subplot()
ax.set_xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
ax.scatter(X, Y, s=4)
plt_canvas.draw()

# Plot the velocities 
t1_values = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 9, endpoint=True)
for t1 in t1_values:
    ax.arrow(f_x(t1), f_y(t1), diff_x(t1), diff_y(t1), head_width=0.02, head_length=0.02, ec='red', linewidth=0.1)
plt_canvas.draw()
```

Comment: That looks quite reasonable already -- can you add a more exact question, please? Like, are you getting an error?

Comment: (And aside: there an [awesome book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/functional-differential-geometry) on what you are trying to do.)

Comment: @phipsgabler  As per the definition of curve length, it is integration of velocities through the curve.  I am trying to find how this can be implemented

Comment: Oh, so just how to do the integration with Sympy? That was not entirely clear to me, maybe add another sentence about what code parts are still missing.

Answer (score 3):

From `geometry` you can define a parametric curve and it can tell you the length of the same. Is this what you were expecting:

```
>>> Curve((cos(t), sin(t)), (t, 0, 2*pi)).length
2*pi
```

SymPy does not yet allow 3-D curves but you can do this in general by defining the point parametrically, then integrating over the range of interest.

```py
from sympy import Tuple
from sympy.abc import t
x=Tuple(cos(t),sin(t),3*t)
ss = sum([i.diff(t)**2 for i in x])
>>> integrate(sqrt(ss), (t,0,2))
2*sqrt(10)*pi
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this for curves in 3D?

Comment: added a note to answer showing how to do this in 3-D (or any dimension)